# How to call logout programmatically in facebook connect using iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, facebook

I integrated FaceBook into my app which is working fine. If user opens the app next time and  click FB button, it wont ask user credential, get login automatically which means keep retaining previous session. can you help me out, how should I logout from FB?

Regards

sri

Answer (score 0):

See 'Logging out' [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk):

Assuming you log in like this:

```
Facebook* facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:appId];
[facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
```

You programmatically log out of Facebook with:

```
[facebook logout:self];
```

Note that the Facebook Connect API on iOS restoring the session between multiple launches is expected behavior, to avoid having users to sign in every time they use the app. You probably shouldn't log out the user from Facebook unless he explicitely wants to do that.

Comment: I tried your code.. its not loging out.. what should I put in fbDidLogout